# Cannot use recordRTC in react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, recordrtc

I cannot import RecordRTC from 'recordrtc'

I have installed the node module, but when I try to import it, i receive the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'recordrtc'. '/Users/jnelson/Documents/GitHub/VidApp/node_modules/recordrtc/RecordRTC.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/recordrtc` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'recordrtc';`  TS7016
```

I've tried simply declaring record rtc as an any type in a .d.ts file but that did not seem to help. I feel like this should be a common issue and either a simple solution or someone has made a .d.ts file for this?

I created the app with react-ionic. The error message above is from a local web browser from my desktop

Comment: did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I don't think so, but I have since moved on and didn't end up using the react-ionic framework. Good luck to you!

Answer (score -3):

Try npm install @types/recordrtc --save

The above error occurred because you are using TypeScript with your React application.